# Can I save the files of all the installations I currently have so that I can install them on an entirely different computer?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, wget

I know that many programs get installed with paticular hardware in mind, and once `apt` is used, it automatically selects the program for your hardware. Like the programs installed on a raspberry pi will be very different to ones installed on an x86 processor and I am sure there are many other things like this.

What I want to do is download as much as possible of ubuntu, updates, apps, as much as possible so that I can install them onto a non-wifi connected computer. I think `wget` would probably be best for this but not sure how to `wget` updates if thats a thing. Also, when using `wget` I would be scared of forgetting some dependencies that would normally be installed when apt gets called. This other computer would be absolutely nothing like the one

I am currently using, currently using blade stealth with intel 7200u and trying to install it on an AMD 2700, so drivers and such I would imagine would be an issue as well. Is this possible to do?

Comment: How about cloning your installation? It might not work, but it's reasonably quick to try. I have successfully cloned virtual machines and installed them on metal, and vice versa, so the driver thing seems pretty forgiving.

Comment: I am a little skeptical on this one, specially network/display drivers, it's a little difficult for me to try though as my installation is 1tb while my only spare drive is 500gb so I can't clone very easily. But I will see if I can test this I will try to run it on my main pc which should be different enough. However, if possible I would also like to "save" certain drivers like nvidia drivers that would be required on the new pc, I imagine this is easier since drivers should be accessible through wget right? Edit: I am using windows for cloning the drive so software is restricting

Comment: Lets-download-everything-and-hope-for-the-best is not a plan. You must think about the uses for which the system will be used. An offline system doesn't need whole slabs of network-related software nor many GB of network-related security updates. Sit down with the end user of the offline system and put together the list of applications to install and remove. Let them know that any future change will be non-trivial and will require a network connection.

Comment: The end user in this case is myself. I understand any big changes will likely require a connection but I simply want to move from my laptop acting as a server to a desktop with airflow/better cpu handling it. I need to no changes to my current setup beside knowing how exactly I can extract it all into some kind of offline installer for all of it. Also would be very useful if I could use that same drive to install certain apps onto other computers, essentially have my server act as a package distributor by simply providing the files for certain applications and other just needing to download

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, in case anyone runs into the same question. [Keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx) is an open source program that does exactly this very easily. It is an older project but I have found it works flawlessly.